# How to change the date of simple_calendar gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a calendar in Rails using simple_calendar.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jZCP7.png)

However, the date of the calendar appears in the image as 2018-08-23.

I would like to display the date on the calendar day by day like 23 instead of 2018-08-23.

**_month_calendar.html.erb**

```
<div class="simple-calendar">
  <div class="calendar-heading">
    <%= link_to t('simple_calendar.previous', default: 'Previous'), calendar.url_for_previous_view %>
    <span class="calendar-title"><%= t('date.month_names')[start_date.month] %> <%= start_date.year %></span>
    <%= link_to t('simple_calendar.next', default: 'Next'), calendar.url_for_next_view %>
  </div>

  <table class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <% date_range.slice(0, 7).each do |day| %>
          <th><%= t('date.abbr_day_names')[day.wday] %></th>
        <% end %>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <% date_range.each_slice(7) do |week| %>
        <tr>
          <% week.each do |day| %>
            <%= content_tag :td, class: calendar.td_classes_for(day) do %>
              <% if defined?(Haml) && respond_to?(:block_is_haml?) && block_is_haml?(block) %>
                <% capture_haml(day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []), &block) %>
              <% else %>
                <% block.call day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
              <% end %>
            <% end %>
          <% end %>
        </tr>
      <% end %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [the documentation](https://github.com/excid3/simple_calendar#month-calendar), you have to call `day` on the `date` object.

I assume that in your case, the `date` object is the one named `day`, so you have to change 2 lines in your view (those inside `if/else` statement):

```
<% if defined?(Haml) && respond_to?(:block_is_haml?) && block_is_haml?(block) %>
  <% capture_haml(day.day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []), &block) %>
<% else %>
  <% block.call day.day, sorted_events.fetch(day, []) %>
<% end %>
```